# Using NFS with Vagrant seems to cause severe permissions issues

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to house my Rails application. Unfortunately I am hitting a blocker in that using NFS to mount my synced folder results in errors with anything reading from or writing to the synced folder; Resque, Solr and even bundler.

Using `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`, for instance, results in:

> Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /var/applications/beatroot/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/sunspot_rails-2.1.1.gem. It may be corrupted.

Reverting to using a non-NFS synced_folder resolves the issue, leading me to believe it's a permissions problem. Unfortunately the performance loss necessitates using NFS.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a solution?

The host is OS X 10.9.2 and the guest is Ubuntu Precise 64.

My vagrant file looks like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|

    virtualbox.name = "beatroot-development"
    virtualbox.memory = 3072
    virtualbox.cpus = 4

  end

  # Provision dependencies from shell
  config.vm.provision :sprinkle do |sprinkle|

    sprinkle.script = "provisioning/bootstrap_vagrant.rb"
    sprinkle.cloud = true
    sprinkle.verbose = true

  end

  # Forward port to Unicorn
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5009, guest: 5009

  # Create a private network to allow for NFS mounting
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.50"

  # Mount our app in the VM
  # We use NFS for performance gain
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/applications/beatroot", nfs: true

end
```

Comment: This really isn't a Ruby question, it's a Vagrant question. It's incidental that Ruby is involved. And, at that point it becomes very off-topic for Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you ask this on [su] instead.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Link to the question on Super User?